# Hiding/toggling iAds & AdMob

Tags: xcode, admob, iad

I'm supplementing my iAds with AdMob when iAds fails to receive ads. What I'm wondering is if it's ok to just animate alpha to 0 for the banner of the network which is not currently supplying ads. I.e. are the SDKs smart enough to handle this or will Google/Apple think I'm trying to cheat them?

I still want to keep both around in case, for example, during a longer user session iAds starts showing up but then fails to receive ads after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about iAd, but I believe AdMob will stop refreshing if it's not visible, so you should be ok.

I'd recommend that you use a mediation solution that can do all of this for you though. AdMob already has a [mediation solution](http://support.google.com/admob/answer/2413211?hl=en) that is seamless to integrate if you're already using AdMob. Just go to [mediation.admob.com](http://mediation.admob.com) and create a mediation placement. Configure it to use iAd and AdMob with eCPM ordering with iAd at a higher value (so it always gets tried first). Then just swap out your AdMob site ID with the mediation placement ID and pop in the [iAd adapter](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/ad-network-mediation) library and you have a mediation solution setup without worrying how to manage the two networks yourselves.